# How to understand the following bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

```
#! /bin/sh
arg=("${@/a/b}")
arg=("${arg[@]/c/d}")
echo $arg
echo ${arg[@]}
```

As I run the above script with different arguments, I get the following results:

```
$ ./a.sh a
b
b

$ ./a.sh  a w
b
b w
```

The script replace the 'a' in argument with 'b'.

However, I'm confused about the use of '/', and I don't understand the expression of arg[@].

Comment: The slash character may be the syntax for replacing (not 100% sure)

Comment: If the script is using arrays, the shebang needs to be `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 3):

In parameter expansion, `${foo/a/b}` replaces the first occurrence of `a` in the value of `foo` with `b`. For the parameter `@`, it replaces the first of occurrence of `a` in *each* positional argument with `b`, and the expansion is, as usual, a series of words corresponding to the original arguments.

```
$ set a ab ac
$ printf '%s\n' "$@"
aa
ab
ac
$ printf '%s\n' "${@/a/b}"
ba
bb
bc
```

`arg=("${@/a/b}")` is an array whose elements are the modified positional arguments. The `/` operator applied to an array expansion behaves the same way it does with `$@`; in this case, the first occurrence of `c` in each element of `${arg[@]}` is replaced with a `d`.

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${arg[@]/c/d}"
ba
bb
bd
```

Finally, `$arg` by itself is equivalent to `${arg[0]}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
${arg[@]/c/d}
```

That expands all the elements of the array `arg[]` and replaces all occurences of c with d.

In a bash shell try this:

```
a=(this is some stuff)
echo ${a[0]}
echo ${a[1]}
echo ${a[@]}
echo "${a[@]/i/X/}"
```

And see what happens

**SUBSTRING REPLACEMENT**:

```
${string/substring/replacement}      - replace first match of substring

${string//substring/replacement}     - replace all matches of substring

${string/#substring/replacement}     - replace substring at front of string

${string/%substring/replacement}     - replace substring at tail of string
```